# Why does "spring-cloud-starter-eureka" pulls "spring-cloud-starter-ribbon"?

Tags: spring-cloud

Why does `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` pulls `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon` as transitive dependency?

I mean, Eureka does not require Ribbon at all - however, the opposite may be true (Ribbon *may* require Eureka depending on its configuration).

We do have a collection of services that just need to register themselves with Eureka but don't need to contact other services. Not having Ribbon direct and transitive dependencies in the game would help to reduce the size of the final artifact.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of Ribbon and its transitive dependencies, one would add the following in its `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
                <artifactId>ribbon-eureka</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <!-- Eureka needs com.netflix.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager 
                 so don't exclude this dependency
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ribbon-httpclient</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
            </exclusion> 
            -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
                <artifactId>ribbon-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
                <artifactId>ribbon-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

At the end, this removes about 3Mb of dependencies from the final artifact.

It is far more than simply excluding a single dependency like `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon` and it requires more in-depth knowledge of the Spring Cloud Netflix library internals to discover what dependencies can be removed.

@spencergibb: I understand your point, but if it is "so easy" to let users do it themselves, I don't see why you couldn't do it inside the framework when building support for Consul and others. At least, it would be done once by people who know what they are doing and would benefit to the entire community.

Having Ribbon out of the game also makes sure Ribbon components don't get initialized "for nothing" when building applications that don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

If it didn't you would also need a `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon-eureka`.  We wanted to be opinionated, so `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` includes `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon` AND `com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka`.  If you want to reduce the size, a simple `<exclude>` will do that.

Comment: I understand, but it could have been reversed: `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` with only Eureka support and `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon` with all the Ribbon stuff, including the Ribbon-Eureka support.

It would provide more flexibility since people are more likely to use Eureka without Ribbon, than Ribbon without Eureka (case of most "standalone" services that just need to register with Eureka).

It is not only reducing the app size, but also potential issues. Having extra useless libraries on the classpath may trigger auto configurations that may interfere with the rest of the application.

Comment: I won't do the reverse, I need ribbon without eureka for other implementations of discovery (consul, zookeeper, etc...).  Is it such a big deal to do one exclusion?